# Converting raster to polygon through ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, vectorization, error-000354

I have a set of raster which I want to convert to the polygon.
Below is the model I prepared, but its showing below error.

I checked the error code, which explains Alter the name to remove any invalid characters. For instance, consider using an underscore (_) in place of a space

I don't have any space in my input files and in the output file I am writing "%Name%".

What exactly I am doing wrong?

I am using ArcGIS 10.7.1 for this.

[image]

Comment: When you look into the code. The output looks like `somethingsomething.tifvector.shp` so you might want to change that. Which you might be able to do with `"%Name%".replace(".tif","")`

Comment: Please always present error messages as formatted text rather than pictures.

Comment: It's not working either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to parse the path. 
Please insert Parse Path in your model through Insert > Models Only Tools > Parse Path, then choose the parse type = NAME. Connect "Value" tool to "Raster to Polygon" as precondition.

For the output, you can write it as %Value%

See attached picture.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just transfer your input raster files into a file geodatabase and save your output (use %Name% tag as you did before) in the file geodatabase  and  run the model

Comment: After transferring in to file geodatabase also its showing succeeded but not the output database is empty. Here is the error message "Executing (Iterate Rasters): IterateRasters C:\Users\srap\Downloads\#Work_Directory\Göteborg-Borås\Processing\Raster_Difference.gdb *.tif TIF NOT_RECURSIVE
Start Time: Thu Jan  9 15:57:46 2020
Succeeded at Thu Jan  9 15:57:47 2020 (Elapsed Time: 1.20 seconds)"